# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que al presionar CTRL + C o CTRL + Z un script bash no se detenga?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell-script, centos

Estoy liado con un script bash, quiero que cuando lo esté ejecutando no se detenga y no se salga del script al presionar:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, envías una señal determinada al sistema, que ejecuta lo que corresponda.

En estos casos concretos, estas son las señales que envían:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> → SIGINT
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> → SIGTSTP

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es usar el comando `trap` para recoger (atrapar) estas señales e invalidarlas:

```
trap '' INT TSTP
```

También puedes usar el número asociado a cada señal, que se ve haciendo `kill -l`:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP  6) SIGABRT  7) SIGEMT   8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL 10) SIGBUS  11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE 14) SIGALRM 15) SIGTERM 16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP 18) SIGTSTP 19) SIGCONT 20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN 22) SIGTTOU 23) SIGIO   24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ 26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGINFO 30) SIGUSR1 31) SIGUSR2
```

Y decir por ejemplo `trap '' 2` para invalidar SIGINT en este caso, pero los números cambian de sistema a sistema y es más práctico usar su nombre.

Con todo ello, puedes hacer una prueba con este script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT TSTP
for ((i=0; i<=10; i++))
do
   echo "pensando"
   sleep 1
done
```

Este script se ejecutará durante 10 segundos y ni <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ni <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> lo detendrán.

Comment: Vale si, eso está perfecto, pero si tu pulsas CTRL C o CTRL Z y seguidamente le das enter, si se sigue saliendo del script...

Comment: @AmandoMatosLoya a mí no, en mi caso (GNU Bash 5.0.16) no me detiene el script. Indica por favor en qué sistema trabajas.

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo solucionado, pero una cosa. tu has puesto que se ejecute durante 10 segundos, como puedo poner que se ejecute infinitamente.

Comment: @AmandoMatosLoya fíjate que hago un bucle. Si quieres que en lugar de bucle sea infinito, haz `while true; do ... done`.

Comment: Considera también aceptar la respuesta si te ayudó, como se comenta en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona todo bien